# Show the following intersection of points given the cevians and some other conditions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider a $\Delta ABC$ such that it's cevians $AD, BE, CF$ are such that $D,E,F\in BC, CA, AB$ respectively. If $ED$ and $EF$ meet the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at $M, N$, show that $A, C, MN\cap BE$ and the midpoint of the $MN$ lie on a circle.

I don't really know how to even begin with this. I have drawn a figure in geogebra but that doesn't really help me. 
Here's the figure (the quadrilateral is shown in red):
[image]

Comment: Aren't $ED$ and $EF$ meet the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at two points each (So in total, must not there be 4 points?)?

Comment: @AsBk3397 I guess the figure is correct. Please recheck. I've only marked A, B, C, you may be able to guess what the other points can be like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=MN\cap BE$, $X=MN\cap CA$ and let $L$ be the midpoint of $\overline{MN}$. Note that $$(M,N;P,X)\stackrel{E}{=}(D,EF\cap BC;B,C)=-1,$$ so by a well-known property of harmonic divisions, $$XP\cdot XL=XM\cdot XN=XA\cdot XC.$$

Comment: I don't know any projective geometry, unfortunately. Can you please explain it in terms of non projective Euclidean geometry?

Comment: Hi @Mathbg, you might find this handout (http://alexanderrem.weebly.com/uploads/7/2/5/6/72566533/projectivegeometry.pdf) useful for learning a little projective geometry. My solution only requires Lemmas 1, 2 and Corollary 2.

Comment: Thanks for the handout.